# Есть ли речевая ошибка в предложении?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли в данном предложении речевая ошибка? Нужно ли **энергичным** заменить на **своевременным** ?
Благодаря **энергичным** противоэпидемическим мерам количество заболевших гриппом уменьшилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не могу согласиться с предыдущим оратором. "Энергичные" меры совсем не синоним "своевременным". Более того, время энергичных мер обычно как раз наступает, когда не предприняты своевременные. В данном содержательном случае это различие как раз актуально: **энергичные** карантины везде, где только возможно, закрытие школ, детсадов, общепита действительно могут уменьшить количество заболевших гриппом... когда провалена **своевременная** вакцинация. Таким образом, выбор между "энергичными" и "своевременными" зависит от того, что вы имеете в виду. Если просто хотите похвалить, ставьте "... энергичным и своевременным"

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки нет, но "своевременные" меры точнее передают мысль.